# Join Duplications

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a problem with a join I have written. it seems to be duplicating the results of a count I am providing it with. What it seems to be doing is multiplying the number of counts times the number of websites that I have a join making a count for. I feel like I could just enter a case statement and say, "give me a count of the total products, where so and such a set of conditions are met" but I don't think that is the 'best' or the 'right' solution. Can someone help me please understand how I can make this query work?

What it is designed to do is show me the number of websites that are signed up for a particular brand, and then the number of products that are signed up for that brand. The part that is not working is that it is showing me the total number of products that are being presented across ALL of the sites. I'd like it so it was JUST showing me the number of products that there actually are in the products tabel.

```
select b.brandName, count(*) as bCount , count(DISTINCT siteID) as 'Number of 
Customer Sites'
from products.products p
Inner Join products.Brands b on p.brandID = b.brandid
Inner join products.sitebrands sb on b.brandID = sb.brandID
where p.status = 1 and p.imageType = 1 and  b.assignedTo = 'Steve Smith'
group by b.brandid
order by bCount ASC, count(DISTINCT siteID) ASC
```

Please let me know what next steps are to get this up and running.

Hope you are well,

Steve

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, can someone show me where the original is?

Comment: There's a link at the top of your question to the post that is a duplicate of your question.